# variavel undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

Olá,

estou tento um problema ao recuperar a variável global `total`em um script.
Em um alert inserido no mesmo escopo ela é exibida normal, porem em uma declaração ela não é retornada, aparece undefined. segue o trecho:

```js
preco = "";
qtd = "";
total = "";

function keypressed(obj, e, f) {
var tecla = (window.event) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
preco = f;
qtd = tecla - 48;
total = qtd * preco;

if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 0 || tecla == 13)
    return true;
if (tecla < 48 || tecla > 57)
    return false;
}

$("#confirma").confirm({
title: "Confirmação",
ERRO >>> text: "O valor total é R$" + total + ", confirmar venda?",
confirm: function(button) {
    button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);
    Aqui aparece normal > alert(total);
},
cancel: function(button) {
    button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);
    alert("Venda não realizada.");
},
confirmButton: "SIM",
cancelButton: "NÃO"
});
```

o alert que coloquei é para verificar se a variável tem algum valor, e mostra o valor esperado, mas na frase `text:"O valor total é...` o valor não aparece.
Qualquer ajuda vale. vlw.

Comment: tentou alterar a declaração dele com o var antes? Assim: var total = "";

Comment: tentei sim, tentei até fazer o calculo em âmbito global mas da o mesmo erro, a variável em si tem valor mas não é retornada naquela posição especifica. outros testes que fiz foi colocar um valor logo na declaração da variável. ai funciona, mas preciso que esse valor seja dinâmico e não predefinido.

Comment: Já tentou converter para inteiro antes de realizar a multiplicação?

Comment: tentei agora, ao me dar a dica, obrigado, mas também não deu certo.

Comment: Eu não conheço essa sintaxe `ERRO >>>`, coloque o código exatamente da maneira que fez e pra comentar linhas use o `/**/` ou `//`

Answer (score 2):

coloquei o $().confirm() dentro da função, resolveu o problema em parte. veja como ficou:

```js
var preco = "";
var qtd = "";
var total = "";
 
function keypressed( obj , e , f) {
     var tecla = ( window.event ) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
     preco=f;
     qtd=tecla-48;
     total=qtd*preco;

    if ( tecla == 8 || tecla == 0 || tecla == 13)
        return true;
    if (tecla < 48 || tecla > 57 )
        {return false;}

$("#Confirma").confirm({
                title:"Confirmação",
Não atualiza>>      text:"O valor total é R$" + total + ", confirmar venda?",
                confirm: function(button) {
                    button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);        
Atualiza normal >>      alert(total);
                },
                cancel: function(button) {
                },
                confirmButton: "SIM",
                cancelButton: "NÃO"
            });
        }
```

vi que o `text:` não atualiza uma variável quando acionada pela segunda vez, apenas pega o valor na primeira vez que o botão é acionado e mesmo alterando os valores input o resultado não muda, para o resolver isso dei um refresh em um ponto específico na página (botão) e deu certo. Essa solução não é correta, uma solução otimizada é bem vindo. vlw pessoal.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos no momento ignorar o código de cada bloco, e ver como o conteúdo é interpretado:

```
total = ""; // declare o valor de 'total'

function keypressed(obj, e, f) {} // declare uma função

$("#confirma").confirm({}); // invoque .confirm() via jQuery
```

Note que nada na declaração da função faz com que o código `$("#confirma").confirm({})` aguarde antes de ser executado. O resultando então é claro: .confirm é chamado antes do valor ser alterado.

Uma solução seria embutir a chamada `$("#confirma").confirm({})` dentro de uma segunda função, chamada a partir da primeira.